# how to disable magnify selected tab in BottomNavigationBar on Android

Tags: android, material-design

how to disable magnify selected tab in BottomNavigationBar Android, I just wanna change the tab's color, don't magnify the tab, what should i do, thanks!

Comment: are you using BottomBar open source library ?

Answer (score 0):

you must have included the three properties

```
app:bb_behavior="shifting|shy|underNavbar"
```

in that remove `shifting` property and the Bottombar will not magnify when selected